# How do I proceed on adding multiple prototype cell's

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to add two prototype cell on my UITableView. However, I don't know how I could verify to be able to "return" the correct cells for each prototype. Can you guys give me a hand?

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if ??? {

        let cell = itensTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! tableviewCell
            cell.nameCell.text = "Oculos"
            return cell
    }else{
        let cellAdicionar = itensTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdAdc", for: indexPath) as! tableviewBotaoAdicionar
            cellAdicionar.botaoAdicionar.text = "Adicionar"

        return cellAdicionar
    }

    }
```

[***Storyboard Picture***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmVBS.png)

Comment: Use the `indexPath` parameter. Check some appropriate combination of its `row` and `section`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your model to answer that inside `cellForRowAt`

```
var arr = ["first","second","first"]
```

//

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let item = arr[indexPath.row]

    if item == "first" {
        let cell = itensTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! tableviewCell
        cell.nameCell.text = "Oculos"
        return cell
     } else {
        let cellAdicionar = itensTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdAdc", for: indexPath) as! tableviewBotaoAdicionar
        cellAdicionar.botaoAdicionar.text = "Adicionar"
        return cellAdicionar
     }
}
```